# ANDROID : Changing the color of ExpandableListView's group indicator

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

The problem : I've changed my app's background color to white, and now I cannot see the ExpandableListView's group indicator anymore.

ExpandableListView has methods to change text color, background color, and divider color, but nothing I can see for the group indicator color.

I do not want to provide custom drawables, I just want to change the color of the drawables that are provided by Android, programmatically.

I feel there must be some simple way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use custom drawables here. You can't change the android drawables provided by Android.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It seems like a strange requirement, having to provide custom drawables just for the privilege of changing the background color.